# Problem with convergence of limiting value in Manipulate

Tags: graphics, differential-equations, performance-tuning, manipulate, version-7

I created a nice Manipulate box of the magnetic field outside and inside a spherical shell placed in an homogeneous magnetic field.  The code is working great, but it has a problem at a limiting value, and the performance is pretty low (slow).  I don't mind much about the slow execution, but I need to find a way to prevent the problem at the limiting value.

Here's a reduction of the code which shows the problem :

```
MagnAxis = {0, 1};
X[s_] := {x[s], z[s]}
r[s_] := Norm[X[s]]

dipField[s_] := 3(MagnAxis.X[s])X[s]/r[s]^5 - MagnAxis/r[s]^3

Coef0[u_, alpha_] := Which[(alpha < 1), 1, (alpha == 1), 0]
Coef1[u_, alpha_] := 3(3 - alpha)
Coef2[u_, alpha_] := - 3alpha u^3
Coef3[u_, alpha_] := 9(1 - alpha) + 2alpha^2(1 - u^3)
Coef4[u_, alpha_] := alpha(3 - alpha)(1 - u^3)

FieldOrientation[s_, u_, alpha_] := 
  If[u < 1,
    Piecewise[{
      {Coef0[u, alpha]MagnAxis, (0 <= r[s] < u)},
      {Normalize[Coef1[u, alpha]MagnAxis + Coef2[u, alpha]dipField[s]], 
         (u <= r[s] < 1)},
      {Normalize[Coef3[u, alpha]MagnAxis + Coef4[u, alpha]dipField[s]], 
         (r[s] >= 1)}}],
    MagnAxis]

Nlines = 40;

MagnCurve[u_, alpha_, n_] := 
  NDSolve[{
   x'[s] == {1, 0}.FieldOrientation[s, u, alpha],
   z'[s] == {0, 1}.FieldOrientation[s, u, alpha],
   x[0] == 0.15(2n - 1 - Nlines)/2,
   z[0] == -3}, 
  {x, z}, {s, 0, 8},
  Method -> BDF, MaxSteps -> 1000000]

MagnGraph[u_, alpha_, n_] := 
  ParametricPlot[
    Evaluate[{x[s], z[s]}/.MagnCurve[u, alpha, n]], {s, 0, 8},
    PlotStyle -> {Directive[Blue]},
    PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"]

Shell[u_] :=  
  Graphics[
    {{Black, Thick, Circle[{0, 0}, 1]},
     {LightGray, Disk[{0, 0}, 1]},
     {Black, Thick, Circle[{0, 0}, u]},
     {White, Disk[{0, 0}, u]}}]

Manipulate[
  Show[
    Shell[u],
    Table[MagnGraph[u, alpha, n], {n, 1, Nlines}],
    PlotRange -> {{-zoom, zoom}, {-zoom, zoom}},
    ImageSize -> 600],
  {{u, 1/3, Style[Subscript[R, 1]/Subscript[R, 2], 10]}, 0, 1, 0.01, 
    ImageSize -> Large, Appearance -> {"Labeled", "Closed"}},
  {{alpha, 0.5, Style["Susceptibility", 10]}, -5, 1, 0.01, 
    ImageSize -> Large, Appearance -> {"Labeled", "Closed"}},
  Delimiter,
  {{zoom, 2, Style["Zoom", 10]}, 1, 3, 0.1, 
    ImageSize -> Large, Appearance -> {"Labeled", "Closed"}}]
```

Now, set the Susceptibility slider to 1.  The field lines are okay (but the output is slow to get).  Then if you set the R1/R2 slider to 1, the field lines turn into simple straight vertical lines, which implies that there is no shell anymore (when the inside radius equals the outside radius : R1/R2 = 1). This is normal behavior.

But when you reduce the R1/R2 slider a bit, the `Manipulate` box just stop and cancels the calculation.  Or you may get a message like this:

> NDSolve::ndcf : Repeated convergence test failure at s = ....'; unable to continue.

Ideally, the field lines should be of the same type as what you get with Susceptibility set to 1 and R1/R2 set to 0.9999 (directly into the value boxes).

Here's a preview picture of a very thin shell :

[image: thin shell]

So what is wrong with my code above?  And how can I improve the performance?  Using `PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"` doesn't much change the execution speed, and the field lines get ugly in some places.

Comment: Your code doesn't work as is, probably because you did not include the definition of `Coordonnees[s]`. Please make sure that your posted code can run on its own by copying it out of your post and trying to run it in a fresh *Mathematica* notebook. We can't help without complete running code.

Comment: @MarcoB, oops! sorry, this is a small mistake made to define a MWE from the whole project.  I fixed that in the question.  Try it again, it should work now.

Comment: You should define `FieldOrientation` so that it is only evaluated numerically.  Your code doesn't work for me at all by the way (v10.1) so I cant really confirm that will help, but I think so.

Comment: Cham - you're code does not run as it is... please check again using a new kernel...

Comment: I don't understand why it isn't working for you.  I tried the code above in a fresh new session of Mathematica, and the code is working.  It is pretty slow however.  Do you get any error or warning messages ?  How to define the ** FieldOrientation** numerically ?

Comment: Does the version-7 tag mean you have only version 7?  It's nicer if the question has all such constraints specified in the text of the body.  Version 7 is now quite old, and there are probably few users who have a valid license key.

Answer (score 3):

In V10 (and probably V9), the problem is that `NDSolve` has trouble projecting onto the discontinuity when the annulus is too thin.  (It looks like it tries to step across it.)  The trick below is to set an event just outside the annulus to restart the integration with a very small step size.  This seems to allow `NDSolve` to properly detect the discontinuity.

```
MagnAxis = {0, 1};
X[s_] := {x[s], z[s]}
r[s_] := Norm[X[s]]

dipField[s_] := 3 (MagnAxis.X[s]) X[s]/r[s]^5 - MagnAxis/r[s]^3

Coef0[u_, alpha_] := Piecewise[{{1, alpha < 1}}, 0]
Coef1[u_, alpha_] := 3 (3 - alpha)
Coef2[u_, alpha_] := -3 alpha u^3
Coef3[u_, alpha_] := 9 (1 - alpha) + 2 alpha^2 (1 - u^3)
Coef4[u_, alpha_] := alpha (3 - alpha) (1 - u^3)

FieldOrientation[s_, u_, alpha_] := Piecewise[{
   {Piecewise[{
      {Coef0[u, alpha] MagnAxis, (0 <= r[s] < u)},
      {Normalize[Coef1[u, alpha] MagnAxis + Coef2[u, alpha] dipField[s]], (u <= r[s] < 1)}},
     Normalize[Coef3[u, alpha] MagnAxis + Coef4[u, alpha] dipField[s]]
     ], 
    u < 1}},
  MagnAxis]

Nlines = 40;

MagnCurve[u_, alpha_, n_] := NDSolve[{
   x'[s] == {1, 0}.FieldOrientation[s, u, alpha], 
   z'[s] == {0, 1}.FieldOrientation[s, u, alpha],
   x[0] == 0.15 (2 n - 1 - Nlines)/2, z[0] == -3,
   WhenEvent[x[s]^2 + z[s]^2 == 1 + 1*^-8, "RestartIntegration"]},
  {x, z}, {s, 0, 8}, StartingStepSize -> 1*^-8]

MagnGraph[u_, alpha_, n_] := 
 ParametricPlot[
  Evaluate[{x[s], z[s]} /. MagnCurve[u, alpha, n]], {s, 0, 8}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Directive[Blue]}, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"]

Shell[u_] := 
 Graphics[{{Black, Thick, Circle[{0, 0}, 1]}, {LightGray, 
    Disk[{0, 0}, 1]}, {Black, Thick, Circle[{0, 0}, u]}, {White, 
    Disk[{0, 0}, u]}}]
```

Output:

```
Manipulate[
 Show[
  Shell[u],
  Table[MagnGraph[u, alpha, n], {n, 1, Nlines}],
  Frame -> True,
  PlotRange -> {{-zoom, zoom}, {-zoom, zoom}}],

 {{u, 1/3, Style[Subscript[R, 1]/Subscript[R, 2], 10]}, 0, 1, 0.01, 
  Appearance -> {"Labeled", "Closed"}},
 {{alpha, 0.5, Style["Susceptibility", 10]}, -5, 1, 0.01, 
  Appearance -> {"Labeled", "Closed"}},
 Delimiter,
 {{zoom, 2, Style["Zoom", 10]}, 1, 3, 0.1, Appearance -> {"Labeled", "Closed"}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Update:**
Replacing

```
Table[MagnGraph[u, alpha, n], {n, 1, Nlines}],
```

with

```
Graphics[{
  Blue,
  Line@Table[{x["ValuesOnGrid"], z["ValuesOnGrid"]} /. 
      First@MagnCurve[u, alpha, n] // Transpose, {n, 1, Nlines}]
  }]
```

saves about 0.8 sec. (out of 2.16) on my machine.  If I reduce the `PrecisionGoal` in `NDSolve`, to

```
PrecisionGoal -> 4
```

I save another 0.2 sec., and the plot is still fairly accurate.  It still takes over a second to compute and render the plot.

Comment: It isn't woking well with Mathematica 7, apparently.  Is this WhenEvent compatible with v7 ?

Comment: @Cham I no longer have access to V7.  The functionality was called [EventLocator](http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v7/tutorial/NDSolveEventLocator.html) in V7 and a similar trick should be possible with it.  I can't reproduce your problem exactly, since I don't have V7, so I'm not sure exactly what problem V7 has with your system, or whether this approach will address that problem.

Comment: The problem is when you set the susceptibility to 1, and R1/R2 to 1 too, then move a bit the R1/R2 slider a bit to the left.  The computation may stop and cancels itself.  I would like to prevent this to happen.  Or in other words, R1/R2 = 1 is a kind of singularity.  I would like to contournate it in some way.

Comment: @Cham I understood that, but what I mean is that I can only reproduce something like your problem in V10 and solve it in V10.  I can't reproduce in V7 and search for solutions in V7 (because I don't have V7).  I only hope my approach might help out in V7.

Comment: Is there any way I could optimize the code for some better performances (i.e. speed) ?  The code is currently a bit too slow for my taste.

Comment: I could limit the first slider (R1/R2) to the 0 to 0.9 intervall, and this would solves most issues.  But it was interesting to show what happens in the case of a very thin shell.  The code also need to be sped up a bit but I don't know how.

Comment: **PrecisionGoal** in **NDSolve** ??  Do you mean in **ParametricPlot** ?

Comment: Yes.  But not in NDSolve with v7.  And 1 sec to render a plot is pretty nice.  For me, it's about 5 sec or more.

Comment: @Cham It's the opposite in V10 (`PrecisionGoal` is for [`NDSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolve.html#30672), not for `ParametricPlot`).  The [V7 docs](http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v7/guide/Mathematica.html) suggest it's the same in V7.

Comment: Oops !  Sorry ! I confounded **PrecisionGoal** and **PerformanceGoal** !

Comment: Hey !  Using **PrecisionGoal -> 5** in NDSolve appears to solve my issue !    :-)  And the compilation and rendering time is about 4 seconds.

Comment: Now, I need to understand the differences between using options **PrecisionGoal -> 6** (say), and **MaxSteps -> 1000000**.  The first option appears to solve my issue.  The second one causes my issue.

Comment: I just had an idea to make the code more robust.  Since it doesn't change the graphical output to give an higher value than R1/R2 = 0.999, I would like to "freeze" all higher values back to 0.999.  What would be the best way of achieving this ?  Currently, I'm using the following code to Manipulate, but I suspect it could be made better : **If[u < 0 || Not[NumericQ[u]], u = 0.5];
If[u >= 0.999, u = 0.999];**.  Any suggestion ?

Comment: @Cham Seem fine.  You could replace the `u` declaration with something like `{{u, 1/3, Style[Subscript[R, 1]/Subscript[R, 2], 10]}, 0, 1, 0.01, Manipulator[Dynamic[u, (u = Clip[Round[#, 0.001], {0., 1.}]) &], #2, Appearance -> {"Labeled", "Closed"}] &}`.  I think that should work in V7, but I don't remember all that's changed since then.